# Find a defined-length number in a sentence and parse it

Tags: javascript, html, regex, dom

I'm reading content from elements on a webpage using javascript that contain paragraphs and wrapping "Article Number"s in anchor tags. Example:

We need to update 25223. (or)  KB25223 needs to be updated.

The main context here is that its always going to be a 5 digit number, but i don't want it to grab 5 digits out of a 6 or 7 digit number. It would either be surrounded by alpha non-numeric or special characters. I'd prefer to use a regexp statement but I don't know enough about modifiers to work around everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's ignore the HTML part, and assume that your text is amenable to being searched with regular expressions.  (Do not try to parse HTML with regexes!)

Let's assume that you have a text in which multiple numbers can appear, and we already have that text in a javascript string, `text`.

What you want looks something like this:

```js
// text variable already contains our text
var re = /(?:\D|\b)(\d{5})(?=\D|\b)/g;
var arr;
while ((arr = re.exec(text)) !== null) {
    var item = arr[1];
    console.log('found item ' + item);
}
```

(I stole that code from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec), if you want to see more details about it.)

The pattern part of the regular expression is enclosed in the `/ /` slashes.  `g` is a flag that means "global": prepare to match all occurrences in the string.

The pattern has three parts.  The essential part is `(\d{5})`.  `\d` means any digit; `\d{5}` means match any digit five times.  The parentheses mean "capture", i.e. save that for later.

The first part, `(?:\D|\b)`, means match any non-digit or any word break, but do not save them for later.  `\D` is a non-digit, `\b` is a word break, `|`  means "or", and the notation `(?: ... )` means group these together, but don't save them.  The reason we need both of these is to match the char before the number in strings like `KB12345` or `this is 12345`, but also to match if the number is the very first thing in the string, like `12345 rocks!`.

The last part, `(?=\D|\b)`, means match any non-digit or any word break, but *don't even count it as part of the match*.  The `(?= ... )` means look ahead to see if it's there.  You need not to count it in case you have a string like `12345y67890`: that `y` has to count as a word boundary for both numbers, so don't include it as part of the match.

Running `re.exec()` once returns an array like this:

```js
[ 'B25223',
  '25223',
  index: 1,
  input: 'KB25223 needs to be updated.' ]
```

`arr[0]` contains the entire match.  `arr[1]` returns what we caught in the parentheses and saved for later.  (If we had more capturing parens, there would be values in `arr[2]` to `arr[`*n*`]`.) `index` is where the match starts in the `input` (the text we're searching in).  `exec()` returns `null` if there's no match.

`exec()` saves the index to start the next match, so it can be run in a loop.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This should match exactly 5 digits and nothing more:

```
str.match(/\b\d{5}\b/g);
```

If you want it to also catch things with preceding letters like KB25223, try:

```
str.match(/(?:^|\D*)(\d{5})(?=\D|$)/g)
```

And then remove the non-capturing portion of the group if necessary.

`str` is the string containing the article numbers

Comment: This would work, however if a number is longer than 5 characters, it just takes 5 digits from that number, where as it should ignore it entirely.

Comment: @TylerFields:No, it doesn't. It takes care of 5 digit numbers only. Did you try it?

Comment: "123456".match(/(?:^|\D*)(\d{5})(?=\D|$)/g) will return 23456. It should not catch that 6 digit number at all.